# How to pass Arguments when call require_ok '*.pl' to test by Test::More

Tags: perl, test-more

I'm wondering the way to test each Subroutings in *.pl files individually.
But Can't use 'require' clause because some *.pl requires Arguments.

for example

```
use Test::More;
require "some.pl"
```

will always fail Test at 'require'.
because "some.pl " required a argument and end with

```
exit(0);
```

of the file.

I just want to test "Func1,usage,...whatever," every subroutings in '*.pl' individually.

some.pl is like that

```
my ( $cmd) = @ARGV;  
if (!defined $cmd ) {
    usage();
} else {
    &Func1;
}
exit(0);

sub Func1 {
      print "hello";
    }

sub usage {
     print "Usage:\n",
    }
```

How can I write a test code for "sub Func1" by "Test::More"?

Any suggestions appreciate.

Comment: What do you want to test `Func1` for? It does not return any value. What do you try to do? [Test::Simple - tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks comment ,Polar.  
poor explanation for my apology.
Update my question.
Still need your help.
Thanks

Comment: Still, your comment in the question is not clear. Normally tests are written to verify that a Module functions produce result properly. As rule return value from some function is compared with expected -- if return value match es then it passed the test. In you case both functions print some string in the terminal and no value returned. Or you just want to see that they fulfill their function -- print "hello" in one case and "Usage" in other?

Comment: Thanks Polar, You are right. now new problem come up one after another.
I have to struggle with this problem you pointed out in next stage.

Comment: If you have a `.pl` file that contains subroutines you want to use externally, it sounds like you have a Perl 4 style "perl library". You should update this to the modern age by making it a [module](https://perldoc.pl/perlmod). Then you can load the module and run its subroutines via the full package name, or import the subroutines from the module into your namespace. Finally you can make a script that also uses the same module, and does the script-specific logic like exit().

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I've taken over these old perl assets from generation to generation . That's why I'm in a trouble.What  you mentioned  "It's OLD STYE" is really consideration to me. I'm a middle level in perl . Updating these files to  modern style shold be paramount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exercise a standalone script that you expect to exit, run it with `system`. Capture the output and inspect it at the end of the `system` call.

```
use Test::More;
my $c = system("$^X some.pl arg1 arg2 > file1 2> file2");
ok($c == 0, 'program exited with successful exit code');
open my $fh, "<", "file1";
my $data1 = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
open $fh, "<", "file2";
my $data2 = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
ok( $data1 =~ /Funct1 output/, "program called Funct1");
ok( $data2 !~ /This is how you use the program, you moron/,
    "usage message not printed to STDERR" );
unlink("file1","file2");
```